# GAE php app to use AWS mysql RDS

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

we are recently planning to build app for our customer. For this we are going on GAE for PHP. 
for storage google offers google cloud sql. But this is bit costly compared to AWS RDS mysql.
Can we connect this app to AWS?